# Retain value of Bulk operation

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7 with views 3.

I have used VBO for a user list view. I select some users for any action and then moves to next page and if I come back to my previous page, the  select boxes (bulk operation) does not retain the checked value. Same happen, if I select users by using filters. How can I retian the selected users while moving to next page?

Thanks in advance for your help.